# I can retrieve values from datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to retrieve some values I put in the data store with a model class name "Ani" and I have tried using the script below to do that but I am having problem with. Can someone please, help me with it

```
import random
import getpass
import sys

# Add the Python SDK to the package path.
# Adjust these paths accordingly.
sys.path.append('/root/google_appengine')
sys.path.append('/root/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib')

from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub

from google.appengine.ext import db
import models

# Your app ID and remote API URL path go here.
APP_ID = 'silasanio'
REMOTE_API_PATH = '/remote_api'
def auth_func():
    email_address = raw_input('Email address: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('Password: ')
    return email_address, password

def initialize_remote_api(app_id=APP_ID,
                          path=REMOTE_API_PATH):
    remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(
        app_id,
        path,
        auth_func)
    remote_api_stub.MaybeInvokeAuthentication()

def main():
    initialize_remote_api()

    Meanvalue = []
    result = db.         ("SELECT * FROM Ani ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1")
    for res in result:
      Meanvalue = res.mean
      std_dev = res.stdev

      print(mean)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I am getting the error below:

raise KindError('No implementation for kind \'%s\'' % kind)
google.appengine.ext.db.KindError: No implementation for kind 'Ani'

Please, I need some help with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the file where you define the class `Ani` before you can run queries on the data.